# Hook to object instantiation

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if there's a way to hook to an event whenever an object is instantiated.

If it doesn't, is there a way to retrieve the object to which an attribute is attached to when the attribute is instantiated?

What I want to do is give some of my classes a custom attribute and whenever a class with this attribute is instantiated, run some code for it.

Of course, I could simply place the code in each of those classes' constructor but that's a lot of copy and pasting and I could easily forget to copy that code into one or two classes.  And of course, would be very convenient for end users as all they would have to do is add my attribute to their classes and not worry about remember to add that bit of code in their constructors.

I actually can't do a base class because all of those objects already have a base.

Thanks in advance.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do.  Either use the attribute's constructor or have an event handler for object instantiation.

```
public class MySuperAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MySuperAttribute()
    {
        //Something akin to this or the event in Global
        Global.AddToList(this.TheTargetObject);
    }
}
[MySuperAttribute]
public class MyLabel : System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
}
public static class Global
{
    public static void AddToList(Object obj)
    {
        //Add the object to a list
    }
    //Some pseudo-hook into the instantiation of any object from the assembly
    private void Assembly_ObjectInstantiated(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MySuperAttribute), true).Count != 0)
            AddtoList(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is interception. If you're willing to pay for it, PostSharp will do it. There's a few other options that I can't remember off the top of my head that are free. They require every object that is the target of interception to be virtual though. PostSharp does not. http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Brandon thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: You may also try the [factory pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874246/Understanding-and-Implementing-Factory-Pattern-i) with a generic method, if it is duable.

Comment: @Eser I read and re-read it and I don't know how to formulate it better, sorry.  My question is there, reason for wanting this is there, example is there.  Don't know what else to add :/

Comment: As mentioned you can use PostSharp. Funnily enough though, this feature seems like it may be possible out of the box in the future coming from this talk from a couple weeks back: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B889 skip to around 50 mins

Comment: @DavidEsteves Oh neat.  Guess I'll wait then.

Comment: Even if all of the types already have base classes, you can add a common base class that goes between all of these base classes and `System.Object`. The parameterless constructor of that base class would be the interceptor you're looking for. This design would require minimum effort I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to hook object instantiation externally, maybe with some debugging API, and it has a good reason. It makes your code harder to maintain and understand for other people.

Attributes won't work, because the instance of an attribute is not actually created until it is required - via reflection, and an attribute is assigned to a type, not an instance.

But you may well put the code in a base class, and derive all other classes from it, although it is also not a good practice to pass half-initialized instance to other methods. If the class inherits from *ContextBoundObject*, you can assign a custom implementation of *ProxyAttribute* to it and override all operations on it.

If you can't create a common base class (when your types inherit from different types), you can always create the instance with a custom method like this one:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : new()
{
    var inst = new T();
    Global.AddToList(inst);
    return inst;
}
```

However, seeing as you inherit from form controls, their instantiation is probably controlled by the designer. I am afraid there is no perfect solution, in this case.